# Exclude variables from object

Tags: javascript

So basically I understand you can loop through an array in either of these ways.

```
var testarray = new Array(1,2,3,4);
for(i in testarray)console.log(testarray[i]);
//outputs 1,2,3,4
for(var i=0;i<testarray.length;i++) console.log(testarray[i]);
//outputs 1,2,3,4
```

My question how can I duplicate/emulate that array.  With support for both of the for loop methods?  Because when I do the same thing but I create my own function it includes length in the 1st for loop.

```
function emulatearray(){
     for(var i = 0;i<arguements.length;i++)this[i]=arguments[i];
     this.length = i;
}                       
var testarray = new emulatearray(1,2,3,4);
for(i in testarray)console.log(testarray[i]);
//outputs 1,2,3,4,null
for(var i=0;i<testarray.length;i++) console.log(testarray[i]);
//outputs 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement shouldn't be used to iterate over an array.

Quoting the [Mozilla Dev Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> #### for...in Statement
>
> Although it may be tempting to use this as a way to iterate over an `Array`, this is a bad idea. The `for...in` statement iterates over user-defined properties in addition to the array elements, so if you modify the array's non-integer or non-positive properties (e.g. by adding a "foo" property to it or even by adding a method or property to `Array.prototype`), the `for...in` statement will return the name of your user-defined properties in addition to the numeric indexes.
>
> Also, because order of iteration is arbitrary, iterating over an array may not visit elements in numeric order. Thus it is better to use a traditional for loop with a numeric index when iterating over arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the reason why you shouldn't use the `for (i in array) ...` construct. The JavaScript array's `length` property is internally declared as non-enumerable, so it doesn't appear when you iterate through the object, but any properties that *you* define are always enumerated.

The upcoming ECMAScript 5 has a way to define your own properties as non-enumerable, but most browsers don't support it as yet.